# Detect circles in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, detection, shapes

I have a problem with choosing right parameters for HoughCircles function. I try to detect circles from video. This circles are made by me, and has almost the same dimension. Problem is that camera is in move.

When I change maxRadius it still detect bigger circles somehow (see the right picture). I also tried to change param1, param2 but still no success.
[image: Left-original picture, Right - after blur and detected circles]

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 25)#cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)


  minDist = 100
  param1 = 500
  param2 = 200#smaller value-> more false circles
  minRadius = 5
  maxRadius = 10
  circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1, param2, minRadius, maxRadius)

  if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(blurred,(i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Maybe Im using wrong function?

Comment: Why param1 and param2 is too high? Try these parameters: **param1=100, param2 = 30, minradius = 1, maxradius = 100**

Comment: does minDist=100 make sense in your image? Try decreasing minDist according to the real distance of those circles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main problem in your code is 5th argument to `HoughCircles` function.

According to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) the argument list is:

`cv2.HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) → circles`

That means the 5th argument applies `circles` (it gives an option getting the output by reference, instead of using the returned value).

Because you are not passing `circles` argument, you must pass named arguments for all arguments after the 4th argument (like `param1=param1`, `param2=param2`....).

Parameter tuning issues:

- Reduce the value of `param1`.
  `param1` is the higher threshold passed to the Canny.
  In your case value should be about `30`.
- Reduce the value of `param2`
  The documentation not so clear, but setting the value around `50` works.
- Increase `maxRadius` value - radius `10` is much smaller than the radius of your circles.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('circles.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 25) #cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)

minDist = 100
param1 = 30 #500
param2 = 50 #200 #smaller value-> more false circles
minRadius = 5
maxRadius = 100 #10

# docstring of HoughCircles: HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) -> circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Show result for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. You're the best :)

Answer (score 12):

Instead of having to fiddle with choosing the right parameters with `cv2.HoughCircles`, here's an alternative approach using contour filtering. The idea is to obtain a binary image with [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) then perform [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to isolate elliptical shaped contours. Finally we [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and filter using [aspect ratio](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html) and [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea). Here's the results:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, median blur, Otsus threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 11)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph open 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)

# Find contours and filter using contour area and aspect ratio
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if len(approx) > 5 and area > 1000 and area < 500000:
        ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (36, 255, 12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```