# Hough Circle way too sensitive

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I am trying to detect circles in an antibiotic susceptibility test image. with my code, it detects 7 circles however it draws way too many of them (you can find the original image and the results in the links bellow) . how can I make the detection accurate?

P.S: I know that the minRadius i want to detect is 20mm≈75pixels and maxRad is 50mm≈190pixels

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image= "atbg.jpg"
img= cv2.imread(image,1)
img_orig=img.copy()
img= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(21,21),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

all_circs=cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=75 , maxRadius=190) 
all_circs_rounded= np.uint16(np.around(all_circs))
for (x, y ,r) in all_circs_rounded[0, :]:
    cv2.circle(img_orig, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 0), 3)
    cv2.circle(img_orig, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)

imS = cv2.resize(img_orig, (600, 540))                  
cv2.imshow("output", imS) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original image:

[image]

Result image:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect circles in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637120/detect-circles-in-opencv)

Comment: I think the OpenCV Hough circle transform is not able to solve this problem. Another implementation of Hough circle detection could work, but the central circle is very hard to detect. In this image the circles are darker than its sorroundings, and OpenCV Hough circle transform does not use this information.

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla I see, in this case, do you know other ways I can use to detect the circles and calculate their diameters?

Comment: Maybe you can first detect the small circles, as they are the centers of the real circles. Once you know the center of a circle, you can cast lines from the center outwards and detect intersections (points) for that given circle. As these points must correspond to the original circle, you can then detect it using RANSAC.

Answer (score 0):

Can you first get the edges of the circles using Canny() edge detection?

Comment: ```cv2.HoughCircles()``` computes a canny edge detector inside