# How would I find the curvature of an image in python?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, math

I have an image of a circle like this:

[image]

I want to figure out firstly, how to get this into a matplotlib-like graphable form. The result should look something like this.

[image]

Then I would like to find the curvature of this circle. and plot that using a heatmap

Is there any way to do this in python? To turn an image into a graph and find the curvature of the image on the graph?

Comment: See [Detect circles in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637120/detect-circles-in-opencv)

Comment: Yeah. this should work. Thanks!